# Java Eclipse: How to view Compile warnings

Tags: java, eclipse, export

I tried exporting a game I have been working on and it says that it is compiling with errors. How would I be able to see those errors, when I click details it just shows:

```
  Exported with compile warnings: ARealGame/src/Window.java
  Exported with compile warnings: ARealGame/src/Board.java
```

how do I view the compile warnings.

EDIT: Fixed my issue. It was my sprites that weren't loading

Comment: So there is nothing wrong anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what version of Eclipse (Kepler, Luna, etc.) you are using or what platform (Mac or Windows) but you can use the Quick Access field (the search field usually located in the top right of the IDE) and type in "Problems." This will give you a suggestion for a window called Problems. Click this and it gives you a window with a table of errors and warnings. Expand the compile errors and it will give you some more detail. You can also double-click it to be taken to the exact line of code.

By the way, I'm working on a Mac at the moment, so I'm not sure how different it is from the Windows version (off the top of my head).

[image]

Comment: There is no difference for Windows version.